# Get username in custom user twig template

Tags: 8

I have a twig template for the compact display of a user where I am able to output the defined content fields. Is there a way to output the username of that user?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`{{ user.name.0.value }}`

should give you what you want.

The preferred way is inject the username as a variable in a preprocess function. To do so, tweak that in your theme's .theme file

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_user().
 */
function yourtheme_preprocess_user(&$variables) {
  /** @var User $account */
  $account = $variables['elements']['#user'];

  $variables['username'] = $account->getDisplayName();
}
```

then in your user template you can use that as `{{ username }}`.

Edit:

To get the full URL:

- In your template `{{ path('entity.user.canonical', {'user': user.id}, {}) }}`
- In yourtheme_preprocess_user(): `$variables['user_url'] = Url::fromRoute('entity.user.canonical', ['user' => $account->id()])->setAbsolute()->toString();`

Comment: The later is preferred so that `hook_user_format_name()` runs to do anything that a site may want for usernames.

Comment: Can the full URL of the user page be retreived in a similar way using the user preprocess?

Comment: Updated response to include 2 methods to get the user page url

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. The template method works fine, but the preprocess gives me the following error:
Recoverable fatal error: Object of class Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemList could not be converted to string in Drupal\Core\Routing\UrlGenerator->doGenerate() (line 192 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/UrlGenerator.php).

Comment: if you use `yourtheme_preprocess_user()` solution, you need to add `use Drupal\Core\Url;` in your theme's .theme file.

Answer (score 20):

The display name is not a field you can configure in `{{ content }}`. You can get it directly from the user entity:

```
{{ user.displayname }}
```

Reference for the php method: [AccountInterface::getDisplayName](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Session%21AccountInterface.php/function/AccountInterface%3A%3AgetDisplayName/8.3.x)

Comment: Should have more votes IMO. This is the equivalent of the preprocess function in the accepted answer but called from the Twig template.

Comment: Definitely the best solution.

Comment: it works. but how can I prevent it's being cached. sometimes it's displaying prevoiusly logged in username. Or If I login with other user in other browser and come back and refresh here, the user name is getting changed.

Comment: @KrishnaMohan, the question is about the user template. If you have a different template this is probably not cached per user. By bubbling up a cache context 
you can cache per user: `{{ {'#cache': {'contexts': ['user']}} }}`. Caveat: Drupal is optimized to cache per user permissions. Adding a per user context to random templates could cause a severe impact on cache performance, depending on the amount of users registered on the site.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is specifically for getting the username in menu.html.twig

The solution of passing the username through macro worked for me.
Setting a variable and passing it into the macro is needed as these are out of scope of the macro in menu.html.twig

```
{% set username = user.account.name %}
{{ menus.menu_links(items, attributes, 0,logged_in,username) }}
{% macro menu_links(items, attributes, menu_level,logged_in,username) %}
{{ username }}
{% endmacro %}
```

Comment: This answer would be more helpful if it also showed how you setup the `logged_in` and `username` variables in a `hook_preprocess_menu()`.