# Print Preprocessed username Field Value in User Template

Tags: 8, theming, users

$account->getDisplayName() Bypasses "username" Field Preprocessing in User Template?

I am trying to print the value of the `username` field of the user account in a `user--custom.html.twig` file.

**MYMODULE.module**:

```
function hook_preprocess_user(&$variables) {
  $account = $variables['elements']['#user'];
  $variables['userName'] = $account->getDisplayName();
}
```

**user--custom.html.twig**:

```
{{ user.name.0.value }}
```

Both the above examples access the username, but seem to access the value directly and circumvent any preprocessing of the `username` field (e.g. `hook_preprocess_username()`), so it looks like I need a different approach.

I have a view that shows the "User" entity so does not use fields and relies on the user template. What am I missing when trying to get the processed value of the username field, instead of the user name DB value for the account?

Related: [Get username in custom user twig template](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/210571/get-username-in-custom-user-twig-template) but different.

In my template, I am rendering `content.user_picture` and trying to render `username`. So maybe I need to load the user instead of both fields? Looking for the processed `username` field value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably looking for the `username` theme:

```
$variables['userName'] = [
  '#theme' => 'username',
  '#account' => $account,
];
```