# Display Themed 'username' in Block

Tags: 8, blocks

I am trying to display the themed `username` in a custom block.

**MyCustomBlock.php**:

```
public function build() {

  $usersData = \Drupal::service('user.data')->get('my_module');

  $usersFromQuery = [];

  foreach ($usersData as $id => $value) {
    if (some logic) {
      $usersFromQuery[] = User::load($id);
    }
  }

  $userList = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
    ->getViewBuilder('user')
    ->viewMultiple($usersFromQuery, 'compact');

  return $userList;

}
```

This gets me all the users I need, but not the altered/themed `username` I need.

In `MYMODULE.module` I am altering the username.

I've also tried:

- `$users = User::loadMultiple($userQuery);`
- `User::load($uid)->getDisplayName()`

but the username is rendered without `hook_preprocess_username()` alters.

I think the issue is similar to needing this: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/278717/79805

```
$variables['userName'] = [
  '#theme' => 'username',
  '#account' => $account,
];
```

but I am unsure how to get the themed username in my block.

**How can I display the altered username in my block?**

---

Update:

Using a helper function in `MYMODULE.module` that creates the markup for the altered username, and `->setUsername()`, I am able to change the username in my custom block.

```
foreach ($usersData as $id => $value) {
  if (some logic) {
    $userItem = User::load($id);
    $userItem->setUsername(markup($id, $userItem->getUsername()));
    $usersFromQuery[] = $userItem;
  }
}
```

But is not really an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You invoke `hook_preprocess_username()` by rendering the template `username`. Since D8 has no longer a theme() function the only way to do this is by putting the template in `#theme` of a render array. In your case multiple times:

```
public function build() {
  $build = [];
  foreach ($usersFromQuery as $user) {
    $build[] = [
      '#theme' => 'username',
      '#account' => $user,
    ];
  }
  return $build;
}
```